# Oculus vibration

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, vibration

I used OVRInput.setcontrollervibration to use the oscillation of the Oculus touch, but I do not feel any vibration at all. The latest information tells me to use ovrhaptics, but I do not have ovrhaptics in my SDK. How should we solve the problem? Help

Answer (score 0):

download the latest SDK. you dont say which one you have but mine has samples with the controller which show vibrations so just look at the code.